# Angular multiple Post and Put request at same time using $q

Tags: angularjs

I want to create dynamic configuration where we need create(post) the record if not already created if it's created need to pass put request for that. In each accordion group there is form but we have only save button to save all. [image]

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on the save button, have it aggregate all the records and determine which ones are new and which are existing. Once you have all the records with their statuses, loop through each of the records and do POST and PUT based on their status.